# File synchronisation tool for OS X with "dry run" option

Tags: macos, backup, file-transfer

I am currently using rsync to mirrors sets of files between multiple drives. What I do is:

```
rsync -rav --delete --progress --dry-run /Volume/example1/somedir/ /Volume/example2/somedir/
```

I then check the output, making sure it's not about to transfer any large files I simple renamed or moved

I then remove the `--dry-run` flag, append `--extended-attributes` and allow the command to run (the extended attributes flag adds a lot of lines to the output, and makes it hard to see what actual files are being transferred)

What am I looking for is a OS X GUI application to simplify this to 2 clicks. Basically:

- It has presets for transfers (source/destination, should delete files missing from source directory etc)
- When you click "Go", it presents you with a list of files that are to be copied and deleted (excluding hiding the metadata files to be copied)
- You click "Really go" and it proceeds with the transfer

I've tried two rsync GUI's, [Yarg](http://alex.turnlav.net/yarg/) and [arRsync](http://arrsync.sourceforge.net/) - neither make support the `--dry-run` functionality.

In short, is there a GUI file-sync tool that allows you to check what files are about to be copied? Does such a utility exist?

Comment: Unrelated, but it's interesting how both those GUIs have a pirate theme.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind paying for a program you might try doing a search at some of the Mac sites that let you know when new versions of programs/updates are released. I know there's a site called Macfixit that is part of cnet and there's also versiontracker. (and probably hundreds of others...)

One program I've paid for (it's inexpensive, ~$35) is called Synk and has a few different versions (standard, pro,...). It does what you're asking for: it will do a preview run of two directories, subdirectories, etc. and tell you what will be updated or deleted.

I think it's a pretty good program and the developer is responsive. My complaint is that I find it confusing to know exactly what is going to happen and why. (However, if I created some tests and really read through the manual I know I could probably figure it out.) At versiontracker you can see it at:
http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/7842

Another piece of software I just found is backuplist+ an rsync GUI. I've just installed it on an old PowerMac G5 to backup a Netgear NAS weekly. The tests I've done show it to work fine. Unfortunately, there is no preview - the thing you're seeking.

Best of luck,
musical